# Relation between homography and inverse perspective transform

Tags: computer-vision, homography

In the context of on-road vehicle detection I've read the [following paper](http://www.vision.caltech.edu/malaa/publications/aly08realtime.pdf) which details on how to compute a transformation matrix that gives a bird-eye view of the road. The road is assumed to be flat and in that context the matrix is seen as a transformation of point in the image to the ground plane. Looking up the homography definition I am tend to believe that in this context the IPT is a homography. Is this true or am I wrong ? Because when I look at the matrix form inside the paper in homogeneous form the last column should be [0,0,0,1]<sup>T</sup> instead of [0,0,0,0]<sup>T</sup>. The ultimate reason I'm asking is because in [this paper](http://web-info8.informatik.rwth-aachen.de/media/papers/icvs11-sudowe-leibe.pdf) a method is presented that uses the gorund plane homography to select a valid range for sliding windows and I wanted to know if the IPT matrix can be used for this.

Thank-you in advanced.